# If $a_n =\frac{n-1}{(n+1)!}$ . How do I workout $a_{n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, ratio

I am currently going through khan academy's ratio test videos/questions and have been finding it hard to calculate $a_{n+1}$ when given a specific $a_n$. The example in the video:

$a_n$ = $\frac{n^{10}}{n!}$

$a_{n+1}$ = $\frac{(n+1)^{10}}{(n+1)!}$

Seemed easy enough to understand but when there are constants involved I'm not so confident. If possible please explain fundamentally so I can apply it to additional questions. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You compute as you did in the example. But lets take the following
$$
a_n = \frac{n-1}{(n+1)!}
$$
and instead of using $n+1$ lets say we want to figure out $a_k$ then we would have
$$
a_k = \frac{k-1}{(k+1)!}
$$
now lets put back $k=n+1$ we find
$$
a_{n+1} = \frac{(n+1)-1}{((n+1)+1)!} = \frac{n}{(n+2)!}
$$
I hope this helps.

Comment: Ahhh it's so obvious now. Simple substitution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is obvious only after you seen it before - now it will be obvious to you moving forward.